# Warp: Binding to Unix Domain Sockets

Tags: haskell, unix-socket, haskell-warp

The example code listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620623/2597135) shows how to make warp listen only on specific hosts.

Furtheremore, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388207/haskell-unix-domain-sockets) shows some basics on how to use unix domain sockets in Haskell.

How can I combine those two approaches in order to make warp listen on (i.e. bind to) a specific unix domain socket (say, `warp.sock`)?

*Note:* This question intentionally shows no research effort as it was answered Q&A-Style.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `runSettingsSocket` with a `AF_UNIX` socket:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.Wai (responseLBS)
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Socket
import Network.HTTP.Types (status200)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Header (hContentType)

main = do
    let port = 3000
    -- Open the socket
    sock <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
    bind sock $ SockAddrUnix "warp.sock"
    listen sock maxListenQueue
    -- Run the server
    let settings = defaultSettings { settingsPort = port }
    runSettingsSocket settings sock app
    -- Cleanup: Close socket
    close sock

app req f = f $
    responseLBS status200 [(hContentType, "text/plain")] "Hello world!"
```

Note that this will obviously only work on unixoid platforms.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: If one wants to use http-client to use that UNIX socket:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Client
import Network.HTTP.Client.Internal (Connection, openSocketConnection, makeConnection)
import Network.Socket.ByteString (sendAll, recv)

import qualified Control.Exception as E
import qualified Network.Socket as NS

main :: IO ()
main = do
    mgr <- newManager defaultManagerSettings {
        managerRawConnection = createUnixConnection
    }
    -- This changes in http-client-0.5, use parseUrlThrow
    req <- parseUrl "http://localhost/whatever"
    res <- httpLbs req mgr
    print (responseBody res)

createUnixConnection :: IO (Maybe NS.HostAddress -> String -> Int -> IO Connection)
createUnixConnection = return $ \_ _ _ -> openUnixConnection "warp.sock"

openUnixConnection :: String -> IO Connection
openUnixConnection addr = E.bracketOnError
    (NS.socket NS.AF_UNIX NS.Stream NS.defaultProtocol)
    (NS.close)
    $ \sock -> do
        NS.connect sock sockAddr
        socketConnection sock chunksize
  where
    sockAddr = NS.SockAddrUnix addr
    chunksize = 8192

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Copied from http-client
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

socketConnection :: NS.Socket -> Int -> IO Connection
socketConnection socket chunksize = makeConnection
    (recv socket chunksize)
    (sendAll socket)
    (NS.close socket)
```